# Isometry of affine space that conserves the area of triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, affine-geometry, plane-geometry

Could you give me some suggestions to prove that an affine transformation of $R^3$ that conserves the area of triangles is an affine isometry?
I do not expect you to give me the solution, only a piece of advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This isn't true. The matrix $$\left[\begin{matrix} 2 & 0\\ 0 & 1/2\end{matrix}\right]$$ preserves the area of triangles, but isn't an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Sorry I did not write I was referring to affine transformation of $R^3$

Comment: In that case, my first thought would be to look at the tetrahedron formed by $0,e_1,e_2,e_3$ and see where it goes. Without loss, you can suppose the affine transformation is linear, so 0 maps to 0.

Comment: If you can show that the images of $e_1,e_2,e_3$ are still orthogonal, then you'll be done by then looking at a triangle with two points in the direction of $e_i$ and the other in the direction of $e_j$.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ is an affine transformation which preserves the areas of triangles.

Our goal is to show that $T$ is an isometry.

By an appropriate translation we can assume $T(0)=0$, hence $T$ is linear.

Since $T$ preserves the areas of triangles, it follows that $T$ is injective, hence $T$ is nonsingular.

Let $S$ denote the standard unit sphere in $R^3$.

Since $T$ is linear and nonsingular, $T(S)$ is an ellipsoid containing the origin in its interior.

To show that $T$ is an isometry, it suffices to show that $|T(v)|=|v|$, for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

Reducing the task even further, it suffices to show $T(S)=S$.

We'll use the term "planar region" to mean a subset with positive area of a hyperplane in $R^3$.

Since $T$ is linear, $T$ preserves convexity and coplanarity.

It follows that $T$ maps convex planar regions to convex planar regions.

By considering limits of sums of areas of pairwise disjoint small triangular regions, it follows that if $D$ is a convex planar region, then $T(D)$ is a convex planar region with the same area as $D$.

In particular, $T$ maps elliptical regions to elliptical regions with same area.

Choosing an appropriate orthonormal basis, we can assume $T(S)$ is the ellipsoid with equation
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$
where $a,b,c > 0$.

Then the cross-sectional ellipses cut out by the coordinate plane have equations
$$
\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1,\;x=0\\
\frac{z^2}{c^2}+\frac{x^2}{a^2}=1,\;y=0\\
\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1,\;z=0
$$
with interior areas 
$$\pi bc,\;\;\;\pi ca,\;\;\;\pi ab$$
respectively.

These $3$ areas must be equal to the areas of their inverse images under $T$, which are circular cross-sections of $S$, all of which are unit disks, hence
$$bc=ca=ab=1$$
which yields 
$$a=b=c=1$$
It follows that $T(S)=S$.

This completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you!! A brilliant proof, with a absolutely clear explanation!! You really helped me!